# Pandas Time-Series: Find previous value for each ID based on year and semester

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I realize this is a fairly basic question, but I couldn't find what I'm looking for through searching (partly because I'm not sure how to summarize what I want). In any case:

I have a dataframe that has the following columns:
* ID (each one represents a specific college course)
* Year
* Term (0 = fall semester, 1 = spring semester)
* Rating (from 0 to 5)

My goal is to create another column for Previous Rating. This column would be equal to the course's rating the last time the course was held, and would be NaN for the first offering of the course. The goal is to use the course's rating from the last time the course was offered in order to predict the current semester's enrollment. I am struggling to figure out how to find the last offering of each course for a given row.

I'd appreciate any help in performing this operation! I am working in Pandas but could move my data to R if that'd make it easier. Please let me know if I need to clarify my question.

Comment: Given your comments to the answers, it would be very helpful if you provided a sample dataset with all the quirks you want the answers to deal with (for example, what about students who skip a semester?).  And actually, it's pretty much always helpful to provide a sample dataset for clarity.

Comment: How can I best format a sample dataset when posting a SO question? I did try to provide one but couldn't figure out the formatting, so I just included the list of variables in. (Just starting out on Stack Overflow, I appreciate all the help - thanks for understanding!)

Comment: I usu just do something like this:  ```df = pd.DataFrame({ 'x':np.random.randn(10), 'y':np.arange(10) })```  It makes it easy for folks to answer if they can work with your data just with a quick copy and paste.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think there are two critical points: (1) sorting by Year and Term so that the order corresponds to temporal order; and (2) using `groupby` to collect on IDs before selecting and shifting the Rating.  So, from a frame like

```
>>> df
    ID  Year  Term  Rating
0    1  2010     0       2
1    2  2010     0       2
2    1  2010     1       1
3    2  2010     1       0
4    1  2011     0       3
5    2  2011     0       3
6    1  2011     1       4
7    2  2011     1       0
8    2  2012     0       4
9    2  2012     1       4
10   1  2013     0       2
```

We get

```
>>> df = df.sort(["ID", "Year", "Term"])
>>> df["Previous_Rating"] = df.groupby("ID")["Rating"].shift()
>>> df
    ID  Year  Term  Rating  Previous_Rating
0    1  2010     0       2              NaN
2    1  2010     1       1                2
4    1  2011     0       3                1
6    1  2011     1       4                3
10   1  2013     0       2                4
1    2  2010     0       2              NaN
3    2  2010     1       0                2
5    2  2011     0       3                0
7    2  2011     1       0                3
8    2  2012     0       4                0
9    2  2012     1       4                4
```

Note that we didn't actually need to sort by `ID` -- the groupby would have worked equally well without it -- but this way it's easier to see that the shift has done the right thing.  Reading up on the [split-apply-combine](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) pattern might be helpful.

Comment: Awesome, this is exactly what I wanted to do! Thanks so much. I had tried using groupby but hadn't been using it in the right way, I'll be sure to read up on the split-apply-combine pattern to be able to use it correctly going forward.

Answer (score 1):

Use this function to create the new column...
DataFrame.shift(periods=1, freq=None, axis=0, **kwds)
Shift index by desired number of periods with an optional time freq

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have a dataframe like this...

```
ID  Rating  Term    Year
1   1       0       2002
2   2       1       2003
3   3       0       2004
2   4       0       2005
```

where ID is the course ID and you have multiple entries for each id based on year and semester. Your goal is to find the row based on an ID and recent year and term.

For that you can do this...

```
df[((df['Year'] == max(df.Year)) & (df['ID'] == 2) & (df['Term'] == 0))]
```

Where we are finding the course by given ID and term and last offering of the course. If you want the rating, then you can do

```
df[((df['Year'] == max(df.Year)) & (df['ID'] == 2) & (df['Term'] == 0))].Rating
```

Hope you were trying to accomplish this result.

Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't quite work for what I'm trying to accomplish. I need the rating of the most recent course for *each individual course*. The dataframe does look like that, but for every row I want the Previous_Rating column to be the rating from the max(year) & max(term) combination. Does that make sense? 

Thanks so much for your help!